# Can I use Heroku buildpacks to deploy to my own local server?

Tags: heroku, amazon-ec2, setup-deployment

I really like the deployment architecture of [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com).

Is it possible to take one of Heroku's buildpacks (e.g. [Heroku's buildpack for Ruby](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby)) to deploy my app to my own server (local Linux or EC2 running Ubuntu), using the familiar command

```
linux> git push localserver master
```

where **localserver** is a git endpoint to which I can push my repository.

If so, is there any place which documents setting up a local or EC2 server to do this as a repeatable process?

Comment: No, not that simple.  A Heroku buildpack is a small piece of the puzzle that simply customizes your application slug.  You need something a bit more comprehensive to reproduce the deploy-on-push functionality.

Comment: See if Dokku meets your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I am not very helpful, but just wanted to mention that Heroku's own blog post about buildpacks says (http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/7/17/buildpacks/):

> Using buildpacks can be a convenient way to leverage existing, open-source code to add new language and framework support to your own platform. [Stackato](http://www.activestate.com/stackato), a platform-as-a-service by ActiveState, [recently announced support for Heroku buildpacks](http://www.marketwatch.com/story/activestate-introduces-stackato-support-for-heroku-buildpacks-2012-06-19).
>
> You can also run buildpacks on your local workstation or in a traditional server-based environment with [Mason](https://github.com/ddollar/mason).

Comment: Mason seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score -3):

No, but I do know there are a couple of open source Heroku clones out there that you can use on your own servers.  Saying that though, a quick Google didn't reveal anything.

Comment: How do you know there are heroku clones out there?

Comment: @irth In fact, there are. For example, [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku) or [Tsuru](https://tsuru.io/).